# Yii2 GridView CheckboxColumn

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a working Yii2 application locally with `GridView` but immediately I deployed it online, I started having issues with it. Below is the error and the code for the `GridView`:

> **ReflectionException** Class \kartik\grid\checkBoxColumn does not exist

**`View File`**

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;

<?= GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                        'options' => [
                            'class' => 'table table-responsive'
                        ],
                        'columns' => [
                            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\checkBoxColumn'],

                            [
                                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
                                'header' => 'Actions',
                                'headerOptions' => ['width' => '40'],
                                'template' => '{view}&ensp;{update}'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]); ?>
```

I have tried to upgrade the version of the Yii2 application but yet I am still getting the same issue meanwhile everything is working fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `'\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'` rather than `'\kartik\grid\checkboxColumn'` you must be working on windows locally the file names are case sensitive on unix.

change the below inside `GridView`

```
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\checkBoxColumn'],
```

to the following

```
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckBoxColumn'],
```